# Match pattern in file and use found strings to extract lines containing the strings in another file, in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk, sed

I am a newbie to the awesome world of shell scripting.

File `b.txt` contains error codes in comma separated text format. The error codes can be matched with this pattern - '`[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}`'. Example of `b.txt`

```
LO-5645,SE-DH68,MY-2255,MI-9878,SY-FC25,
ER-55R8,LO-5645,
EU-1C07,ER-9871,EY-5523,MM-2564,
FO-D389,XU-2659,EU-1568,
etc etc....
```

File `a.txt` contains in each line a error code and a description of the error code. Example of `a.txt`:

```
EU-1568: system not initializing
ER-55R8: fatal error on platform xx22
MM-2564: Driver not initialized
LO-24DE: Lot failed
SY-FC25: System error on domain
etc etc.....
```

I want to combine info in these two files such that I can create a file `c.txt`, that contains the comma seperated errors along with description of the error message extracted from `b.txt`.

Example of intended result in `c.txt`

```
LO-5645,SE-DH68,MY-2255,MI-9878,SY-FC25: System error on domain,
ER-55R8: fatal error on platform xx22,LO-5645,
EU-1C07,ER-9871,EY-5523,MM-2564: Driver not initialized,
FO-D389,XU-2659,EU-1568: system not initializing,
etc etc...
```

My idea to approach this problem: I was trying to use a while loop to read line by line b.txt, and use `grep -o` to match exactly the pattern of the error codes into a array variable. Then using a internal `For` loop I try to read one element of this array at a time and match lines containing the error code in a.txt.

It would be great if I can get some of your ideas on how I can approach this solution in a better way.

Awk, Sed, grep, perl, cut are all welcome.

Comment: What is more than one error code in one line has error description in `a.txt`?

Comment: And if you don't at least *try* to do it with your limited scripting skills, how will you ever get any better?

Comment: @ Matt Jacob, I have posted this question with an intention of getting ideas to approach this problem in the proper manner. I am just being honest in my above question that without some tips I tend to fall in the trap of using loops to read line by line.

Comment: @ anubhava, the file a.txt is something I got to create via my script, it will always contain one error code and a description in each line.

Comment: On SO, people like to see some effort or attempt at solving the problem on the part of the person asking the question. Even if it's just a list of steps that you think you *might* take, something is better than nothing. The way your question is currently written sounds like a requirements document for someone you've hired to do the work for you.

Comment: Okay Matt Jocob, I do understand your view, I will edit the question I posted tomorrow, to include the solution direction I was trying too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks for exact match**

```
awk -F'[,:]' -v OFS=',' '
 FNR==NR{error[$1]=$NF;next}
 { 
     for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)if($i in error)$i=$i":"error[$i]
 }1' a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F'[,:]' -v OFS=',' '                 # Call awk, set input field sep
                                          # , and : awk supports multiple field sep
                                          # and output field sep as comma

 # Here we read file a.txt

 FNR==NR{                                 # this is true when awk reads first file
                                          # When awk reads from the multiple input file, 
                                          # NR variable will give the total number 
                                          # of records relative to all the input file. 
                                          # FNR will give you number of records 
                                          # for each input file.

           error[$1]=$NF;                 # populate array named error
                                          # such that array index is col1
                                          # and array value is last field of record
                                          # NF gives no of fields in current record

           next                           # The next statement forces awk to immediately 
                                          # stop processing the current record and 
                                          # go on to the next record 

 }

 # Here we read file b.txt

 {
     # NF gives no fields in current record,
     # start loop from first field/column to last field/column( NF )
     # increment by 1 

     for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)

             # check if column value exists in array error

              if($i in error)

                     # if above if statement is true, then we 
                     # have error description so
                     # modify current column 
                     # current column = current column : and your description
                     # which exists in error array

                     $i=$i":"error[$i]

 }1                  # 1 at then does default operation print $0 (print current row/record)
 ' a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

**Input**

```
$ cat a.txt 
EU-1568: system not initializing
ER-55R8: fatal error on platform xx22
MM-2564: Driver not initialized
LO-24DE: Lot failed
SY-FC25: System error on domain
etc etc.....

$ cat b.txt 
LO-5645,SE-DH68,MY-2255,MI-9878,SY-FC25,
ER-55R8,LO-5645,
EU-1C07,ER-9871,EY-5523,MM-2564,
FO-D389,XU-2659,EU-1568,
etc etc....
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[,:]' -v OFS=',' '
FNR==NR{error[$1]=$NF;next}
{ 
     for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)if($i in error)$i=$i":"error[$i]
}1' a.txt b.txt
LO-5645,SE-DH68,MY-2255,MI-9878,SY-FC25: System error on domain,
ER-55R8: fatal error on platform xx22,LO-5645,
EU-1C07,ER-9871,EY-5523,MM-2564: Driver not initialized,
FO-D389,XU-2659,EU-1568: system not initializing,
etc etc....
```

Comment: @ Akshay Hedge, thank you very much for pointing the typo in the sample input file. I am very interested in trying the "Looking for exact match" solution direction.

Comment: The "Looking for just error code" idea is not robust since the numbers  in the substr can be the same for 2 different error codes

Comment: @DineshKumar: Ok if that is the case 1st will do your job, I deleted second one

Comment: Downvoters I willl be glad if you can throw your comment as well, why voted down ?

Comment: @DineshKumar: there is one more typo `MN-2564` in your `b.txt`, I just fixed it

Comment: Hi Akshay Hedge, the solution worked like a charm for me. Thank you so much. 
Would you be able to explain this part of your solution, `FNR==NR{error[$1]=$NF;next}`I would like to use it elsewhere in my script

Comment: @DineshKumar: added explanation

Comment: @ Akshay Hedge, Thank you very much, now I can use this idea for a similar problem I am facing with a different set of data.

Comment: Ultimately it is up to you whether you answer a question, and sometimes a question asker is so stuck that it is just nice to give them the assistance they need. However, we try to balance this out by trying _not_ to encourage the idea that Stack Overflow is a platform for specifying requirements and expecting volunteers to complete the whole thing.

Comment: @halfer: Whatever you said is true, but for right solution if you receive downvote, it is really discouraging, as you know we all are volunteer here, not paid to help anyone, during our free time, or we make our time free to help someone,  it is very bad  if reader shows his frustration on us.  even if you give complete solution you get downvote, and incomplete partial solution also you get downvote, may be someone is targeting me as a anonymous user, ultimately either I should stop answering or I should delete answer which given already.

Comment: @Akshay: you're worrying about DVs too much - don't take them personally. You've received 35+ and 2- so you have profited just fine from this answer. Even if you make a loss, there is satisfaction to be had in knowing you helped someone, right? `:-)`

Comment: @halfer: True, thanks for encouraging, your encourage means a lot for me.